# Simple harmonic motion as projection of circular motion

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Can we consider $\omega$ (angular frequency) in equation of simple harmonic motion (SHM) as the angular velocity of the object in circular motion, when we see simple harmonic motion as projection of circular motion?

Comment: Short answer: yes, but if and only if the circular motion is **uniform** circular motion

Comment: Then if it's correct, it means angular frequency w=2pie/T should be equal to angular velocity w=v/r of the particle executing shm

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Have you learned about rotations in phase space?

Comment: In fact, this explains why the harmonic motion is sinusoidal, but not along any other periodic function.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Oscillation as projection]

Yes. The point on the circle with radius $R$ revolves around the centre, with angular velocity:

$$\omega=\dot{\theta}=\frac{\mathbf{d}\theta}{\mathbf{dt}}$$

The projection on the RHS axis, call it $y$, is:

$$y(t)=R\sin(\omega t+\phi)$$

where $\phi$ is the angle $\theta$ at $t=0$.

Comment: but do u really think the ω in (ω=θ) is equal to the ω in (y(t)=Rsin(ωt+ϕ)). basically my Que is can we really think the angular frequency in a shm as angular velocity of the object when we manipulate the motion as the shadow projection of circular motion (the the object is moving in a circular motion)

Comment: Please note: $\omega=\dot{\theta}=\frac{\mathbf{d}\theta}{\mathbf{dt}}$

Comment: It's more an analogy. But *mathematically* the projection of the position vector (red) of a particle moving uniformly on a circle onto any axis corresponds **exactly** to the description of an SHO.